# Appending existing zip file to form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I am trying to upload an existing zip file to a FormData instance but I am not sure what to pass as second parameter at `.append()`

```
 var theFile  = "http://localhost/Portal/APP.ZIP";
 var myFormData = new FormData();
 myFormData.append(theFile, ? );
```

What should I pass there?

Answer (score 1):

The `append()` method of the FormData interface appends a new value onto an existing key inside a FormData object, or adds the key if it does not already exist.

**Parameters**

`name`
The name of the field whose data is contained in value.

`value`
The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File).

`filename` *Optional*
The filename reported to the server (a USVString), when a Blob or File is passed as the second parameter. The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename for File objects is the file's filename.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: I want to highlight the most useful point for me here. : The default filename for Blob objects is "blob"

Thank you. That was an important hint